# Viewcontroller flashes when it appears

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewanimation

I have one `UIViewcontroller` with menu button....when i click on menu button the other view controller add as a childview. but during this process it flashes and i don't get a smooth result...

look at this image

[image]

and here is my menu view controller image and its hierarchy..
[image]  [image]

Here is my code for button click...

```
MenuVC *objMenu = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MenuVC"];
objMenu.btnMenu = sender;
[objMenu setDelegate:self];

[self.view addSubview:objMenu.view];
[self addChildViewController:objMenu];

[objMenu.view layoutIfNeeded];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{

    objMenu.conLeading.constant = 0;
    [objMenu.view layoutIfNeeded];

    [objMenu.view setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2f]];

    [sender setEnabled:YES];

} completion:nil];
```

So the question is how can i get rid of this flash?

Comment: add some delay before showing the child and then check.

Comment: Have you used any third party library for side menu bar?

Comment: @NileshPatel No...not using any third party library...just displays with instantiate and animate it

Comment: [objMenu.view setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2f]];
 Why you have added this line?

Comment: No...i can't becuse its my viewcontroller and if i remove it it gives me whole white color....let me  post an image of my menuVC

Comment: You are calling [objMenu.view layoutIfNeeded]; twice, Can you please tell me why?

Comment: after animate i make leading space to 0 of the menuVC

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76645/discussion-between-bhavin-and-nilesh-patel).